# Referential Integrity in List View

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I have made an extension in TYPO3 v4.5 with the Extension Builder. Now I have some Tables, that don't have a create/update function, because they don't change very often (only once in some month). To change them, i want to use the list view in TYPO3.

That works, i can create and update my records. But if i have a record, that's in a relation with an other record, i can simply delete it. The other record now has a invalid value.

For example:

```
Books
_________________________
| Name        | AuthorID |
-------------------------
|Harry Potter | 1        |
-------------------------

Author
_________________________
| ID | Name              |
-------------------------
| 1  | Rowling           |
-------------------------
```

Now if I delete Rowling, I have "Invalid Value" in my AuthorID field.
Can I prevent this?

EDIT: Okay, I've found an way how I COULD prevent this: I have to use a predb hook in a TCE for my Extension. But this code (only for experimenting) does not work if i delete a record. I thought that I'll get an array element named 'deleted' with the value 1. But it does not appear. The other data (if I alter the information or make a new record) appears.

```
    /**
     * @param string $status
     * @param string $table
     * @param int $id
     * @param array $fieldArray
     * @param tce_main $tcemain
     */
    function processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray($status, $table, $id, &$fieldArray, &$tcemain) {
        $fp = fopen('../../typo3conf/ext/test/hooks/output.txt', 'w');
        for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($fieldArray); ++$x)
        {
             fwrite($fp, "key: ".key($fieldArray)."\tvalue: ".current($fieldArray)."\n");
             next($fieldArray);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

EDIT2:
Like in the comments in the first answer, I can use status == delete to check if typo3 is going to delete a record. But how prevent this, if i can't change the data in the deleted attribute (because it isn't in the fieldArray)? Anyone a clue?

Thanks for responses
Agash Thamo.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply overwrite the delete method in your repository and check if there is a reference to other objects.

Comment: I thought that the List view directly writes in the database with the TCA? Will simply edit my repository really avoid this? 
By the way: I don't have any delete method in my repository. It's only extends the standard extbase-repository. Do I have to add one? And overwrite the standard?

Comment: I dont know how your extension setup looks like, but there are two ways in my opinion. The first could be your repository. If u add a delete-method u could check the foreign key. The other way could be an index in the database. if u setup the foreign in your fields, typo3 couldnt delete this, or u delete cascade.

Comment: The problem is, typo3 does not delete any records. It only sets a flag named 'deleted'.

Comment: damn right. there is still one possibility more. u can write a hook like here *http://typo3.org/documentation/article/how-to-use-existing-hooks-in-your-own-extension/

Comment: I tried a hook. I'll edit the question with the code, it does not work, maybe you know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: did you already search for it? http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-german/2008-June/047760.html

Comment: Damn I'm stupid. I can use $status == 'delete'! Thanks for the link that helps!